# Displaying an external image in an web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, fileinputstream

Our application displays an external image (client logo) which is specific to each client in an multi-tenant environment. The location of the image file is determined dynamically at runtime and the image stream (as bytes) is transfered to the output stream of the browser in an servlet. It is done as below

```
private void sendFileToDownload(HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileNameWitPath));
    OutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
    resp.setContentLength((int) inputStream.getLength());
    try {
        writeFileToOutput(inputStream, outputStream);
    } finally {
        finalize(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
}

private void writeFileToOutput(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[32 * 1024];
    int count;
    while ((count = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(b, 0, count);
    }
}

private void finalize(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    try {
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.debug("IOException was caught while flushing the output stream.", e);
    }
    inputStream.close();
}
```

In an load test we found that opening a file and closing it are costly operations when multiple threads (~300) perform the same operation. Especially the execution of the FileInputStream constructor.

I wanted to get ideas on what alternatives we could have to display an external image in a java ee web application.

Note we cannot give the path to the image in the src attribute of the img html tag because of security reasons. The client browser won't have access to the external image location. Only the application server would have access to it.

Comment: Do you have some kind of reverse proxy sat in front of your application server? If so that could open up some possibilities for image caching to take some load off your app server.

Comment: Do you mean to say that there are no other better alternatives to the above code? I understand reverse proxy is an alternative but currently we do not have a web server in front of the application server. Also there are other issues with the reverse proxy. How do we provide the image location (which is decided by the server side code at runtime) to the reverse proxy and would the proxy be aware of any changes to the file being made? etc...